# Recieving wrong values from JSON API

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api

I have the following code:

```
var urlKraken1 = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC?pair=XBTUSD&interval=1";
request({
    url: urlKraken1,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        var valuesArray = [];           
        var cur = body.result.XXBTZUSD.length -1;       
        var time = body.result.XXBTZUSD[cur][0];
        var high = body.result.XXBTZUSD[cur][2];
        var low = body.result.XXBTZUSD[cur][3];
        var open = body.result.XXBTZUSD[cur][1];
        var close = body.result.XXBTZUSD[cur][4];
        var volume = body.result.XXBTZUSD[cur][6];
        var Currency1 = "BTC";
        var Currency2 = "USD";
        valuesArray.push([time, "kraken.com", Currency1, Currency2, high, low, open, close, volume]);
        writeMultiRows("kraken.com", Currency1, valuesArray);
}
```

But in my database I'm getting values which are not correct with the ones from the API.
Data I receive for example:

```
time = 1499280240 
high = 2609.001
low = 2608.666
open = 2609.001
close = 2608.666
volume= 12.42484963
```

But I should receive:

```
time = 1499280240
high = 2610.000
low = 2605.022
open = 2609.001
close = 2610.000
volume= 15.42483298
```

Thanks in advance for every kind of tips and help!

Comment: check the browser developer tools network tab for the request - is the correct data coming from the server? if not, then client side code (the only code you've shown) isn't the problem

Comment: looks like you should be currently getting - `1499319720,"2594.179","2594.179","2594.179","2594.179","2594.179","0.10000000",1` did you want the last or the second to last values? - for second to last values, use `var cur = body.result.XXBTZUSD.length - 2`

Answer (score 1):

The data which your assigning is wrong.
press f12 and open network tab and check the network response to see the exact data...
Assign the  array accordingly...